# How to import android open source library?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I tried to use [Android-PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh) in my project.

I am used to importing library by "File -> New -> Other... -> Android -> Android Project from Existing Code" in Eclipse, but this time, it said that "Select at least one project" when I choose the "library" folder in that project.

What is the correct way to import this library? Please help. Thanks!

Comment: If your workspace having the project with the same activity name as the activity in your library, this time also it will show select atleast one project. check if you work space contains any

Comment: Oh, yes! I have another project called "library" in my project list. It works after I changed the name to "pulltorefresh-library". Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your workspace having the project with the same activity name as the activity in your library, this time also it will show select atleast one project. check if you work space contains any

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to import a library into Eclipse, then you may refer to this post [Adding a library/JAR to an Eclipse Android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642928/adding-a-library-jar-to-an-eclipse-android-project)

If you are trying to import the project, then you select the entire project folder.

Comment: I am trying to import a library (the "library/" folder in [chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh)), but there is no jar file.

Comment: Right click on your project in Eclipse and hit "Properties", then "Android", and a screen should pop up for adding this. Further reading can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5991299/java-eclipse-android-beginner-question-how-to-add-libraries-or-linked-folder