# Using android library project as Jar in another android project to reuse the resources

Tags: android, android-layout, android-library

I converted the library project res,gen,src as jar and i use it as referenced library in another project..........but i cant able to access the resources of that jar..........i think iam having issue in gen R.java file.........howw to solve this issue so that i can access those resources of jar(library project)

Don't need the option of include it as library project I only need it as jar......so i can reuse it another android projects

any kind of idea will be helpful........thanx in advance

Comment: For now, there's no way to do that. As @stealthcopter and J.J. Kim 's said.

Answer (score 1):

I Posted this topic below link.

[using jar with res](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995004/packaging-android-resource-files-within-a-distributable-jar-file/7117422#7117422)

**remember that you have to copy res files to the project you want to use them with jar.**

Comment: thanx for the idea
it means that we have to copy each and every resources of our jar/library project into our android project

Comment: I get an error message when I do this saying `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.devspark.appmsg.R$color`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot currently include resources via a jar, you will need to copy and paste them into your current project. [anddev discussion](http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?p=30725)

Comment: thanx for idea, it means that I have to copy each and every resources of my jar/library project into my android project

Comment: Yeah, it sucks, just copy the whole /res folder.

Comment: I get an error message when I do this saying `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.devspark.appmsg.R$color`. Any ideas?