# How to deal with thousands of audio resources in android app

Tags: android, audio, resources, mp3, media

Is there any good solution to deal with thousands of audio resources (mp3 format, 30Mb in total) in an android app? And these resource should be packed into one file that separated from the main app. Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you mean you want to load audio from server?

Comment: what if not from server, but a file?

Comment: then you need to store in sdcard and load

Answer (score 0):

While android app may be available to download over the air, make installation of database file as an additional installation step.

Provide a link on your web-site to download huge database file to a desktop computer and store it on memory card of an usb-connected android device.

Comment: Yes, And how to play audio in database file?

Comment: In this case "database" is a metaphor. I do not mean SQLite or another real database. It may be your own format, or even a jar-file with zero-compression (for faster access), that contains mp3 files. You can get an mp3 file from jar-archive. If performance is not good, consider use of memory card filesystem as a database. I.e make folder structure upon installation of database file on device memory card. And save mp3 files to this folder structure.

Comment: Would you give me some details about how to play mp3 in jar-file in android?

Comment: As an option, extract an mp3-file from jar to a temporary location to play it. Also check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983617/android-jar-libraries