# Packaging a jar for Android

Tags: android, jar, dependencies

I have modularised some simple classes into their own project for reuse elsewhere. These classes typically contain only fields and accessor methods (i.e. nothing Android specific).

They are later packaged up using `ant`'s [jar task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html) and stored in a Maven repository.

In an Android project, I've stored said `jar` file into a `libs` directory and added to the build path. On running the emulator however, I get a "class not found" exception relating to my package. Other third party libraries (such as GSon) are being picked up fine.

Are there any specific steps required to make a `jar` file compatible with Android? ([This reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1983645/412049) seems to suggest otherwise). How can I debug this further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was a result of compiling the `jar` to Java 7. Android [does not support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153989/java-7-language-features-with-android) Java 7 (yet).

Compiling to Java 6 bytecode by setting `target="1.6"` in `ant`'s [javac task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

No as long as you do not need e.g. classes from javax.* that are not in Android. If I were you I would consider looking at using the [Android Maven Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/) for your build though. Check out the morseflash example from the official samples collection. It showcases exactly your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You only need an Android library project if your going to be reusing Android components and resources. In your case, I believe you added the project to the build path, but I'm sure your not exporting it as part of the dependent project.

So open the project properties, open up the *Java Build Path* options and make sure that you have your JAR selected as an exported dependency in the *Order and Export* tab.

**UPDATE**

This is what your entry should read:

```
 <classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="libs/tlvince-dao-0.1.0.jar"/>
```

I've also forked an [updated version](https://gist.github.com/1490261) of your gist.

Comment: Could you add a gist of your project's *.classpath* file so we can debug?

Comment: I tried with and without `exported="true"` still to no avail :( As mentioned previously, `GSon`, with same `classpathentry` *works*, which leads me to believe there is a discrepancy in the `jar`